# Access windows shared folder via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, file-sharing

I have a specific requirement of being able to access a shared folder present on a windows 8 laptop. However, rather than doing this over the wireless connection, I want to be able to do this over bluetooth. So for example, if I have a shared folder on windows called Share and i drop a file in the folder called test.txt, I want to be able to see this file automatically updated on a folder called Share present on the android device, something like what dropbox does but just not over the wi fi. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old as hell question, but I thought I would answer anyway.

Simply put, this is impossible with the way you'd want to implement it.  Windows folder shares are SMB/CIFS, which is a NetBIOS/TCP/IP protocol.  Bluetooth is, well, the Bluetooth protocol.

Technically speaking, you could use Internet Connection Sharing (ICS) on your Windows machine and connect to the broadcasting WiFi.  You'd then be on your internal network, and you could access the share.  But that would involve using your device's WiFi, not your Bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can be done although it is irrelevant for larger files. You just need File Transfer Profile (FTP), which comes with most Bluetooth suites. If its an older Bluetooth driver then you can find the Bluetooth FTP here: [Bluetooth File Transfer (BlueFTP)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/bluetooth-file-transfer-blueftp/9nblggh627zb)

The received files are used store in Documents\Bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

To add on to a more practical solution, this is a possible and can be achieved using this simple workaround:

You need a good file explorer for android capable of supporting network location folders.

In this illustration, I used ES Explorer. Also note your PC needs to support bluetooth browsing.

- First step, in the Bluetooth setting on PC allow bluetooth discoverability. See below:

[image]

- Secondly in your Android device be sure to switch on Bluetooth (pairing the two devices is preferred), open ES explorer, and go to Network >> Bluetooth, see below:

[image]

- Next tap on "Scan" and you should see your PC device like shown below.

[image]

- You will prompted by the PC to grant access to browse folders on PC and click "Allow", after that you can  see the folders on your PC **through your phone** and file transfers are synced, and you just need to refresh to see the changes, (for example you can send a .txt to your Bluetooth exchange folder and see the changes in your phone)

[image]

Note: You can change your Bluetooth exchange folder in Bluetooth settings in your PC to any desired folder. I just used default

[image]

The post may be old but may assist those eho want to substitute ftp file transfers via bluetooth instead of Wi-Fi. Hope this helps